# Job based on development

Tags: jobs

Are there any companies that offer jobs based on games or app development by an individual in his profile, with out any certificate from any institution ?

Comment: Often, game companies will offer jobs based on what the employee can do, not on an education basis. If you have a portfolio of what you can do, good. If you have a portfolio and you have been to school, well you have better chances because often you'll learn better techniques in education programs than by yourself. And of course, this all depends on the job you're looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about education/employment.

Comment: eh it's borderline. This is a question about the game industry specifically and not just employment in general.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all jobs in game development are as you describe. I say "pretty much" because, while most if not all job ads will list a degree in the requirements, they really care more about your skills and the games that you've made. Of course, those games have to be *really* awesome to make up for deficits in your educational background. But I mean, Carmack never finished college, and he programmed Doom.

Comment: Yep exactly. They often say degree or equivalent experience, but mostly they really just want people with experience.